# Store string in vector with unknown size during input

Tags: c++

I have been trying a while to do that but sadly i couldn't and it interests me to do such a thing, i always wanted to have a array of strings! Let's say i have a loop where i gather strings -

```
std::string input;
std::vector<std::string> svec;
int i = 0;
while (std::cin >> input) {
    svec[i++] = input;
}
```

I'm unable to do

```
svec[i++] = input;
```

and I want to find a way to allocate the vector without giving it exact size( unknown  amount of strings), how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before accessing some index, this element needs to exist.
To insert new elements, use push_back

```
svec.push_back(input);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Why not provide an **English** language reference rather than a German one?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't even notice that :D Just copy-paste from a Google link... fixed

Comment: It's better in the original Klingon really.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
svec.push_back(input);
```

(There's good documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Comment: Thanks, really, actually i shouldn't even ask, but i'm at 97th page on Principles and Practice Using C++ 2 and i found vector, it was storing string so i felt like omg this is cool, tried to do that before i've read about .push_back() in book and well I made a useless question.. Sorry for it and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Isuck I've seen far worse questions; at least you explained what you needed clearly.